# How To Display random ads in my web site

Tags: php, html

Hi I want to display random ads in my product page, my all products call in the while loop to display in home page, i want to add ads from backend in between these products randomly in same design as product display like in freekaamaal

How I display these ads in between products can you give me the idea ??

[see this for more info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXWKM.jpg)

```
<div class="products-grids">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <?php

        $id=$_GET['id'];

        $result1 = mysqli_query($con,"select * from products1 where sta='Active' order by id DESC LIMIT 0 , $resultsPerPage");
        while($ro = mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
        {
            $nam1=substr($ro['pne'],0,60);
            $url1=$ro['url'];
            $description1=substr($ro['description'],0,200);
            $price1=$ro['price'];
            $price11=$ro['price1'];
            $bid1=$ro['company'];
            $image=$ro['image_name'];
            $time=$ro['time'];
            $tag=$ro['tag'];
    ?>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="hentry post1 id="post-225396">

         Display Product in loop

        </div>
    </div>
    <?php } mysqli_close($con);?>
<!--    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="hentry post1 id="post-225396"><img src="ads.jpg"></div>
    </div>  -->
</div>
<div class="clearfix"> &nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: You haven't understood how to use stack-overflow : [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: are you using only php or cms like wordpress or something

Comment: its on core PHP @nirpendra

Comment: so, did any of the answers worked?

Answer (score 0):

Anyways your question is too broad.

Here is step by step solution.

**FRONTEND HTML + PHP**

// TWO HARD DIV'S + THREE RANDOM ADS , BUT ONLY ONE OF THE AD GONNA TRIGGER.

```
<?php $random_number = rand(0,2); ?>

<?php ads($random_number,0); ?>
<div>your image or whatever</div>
<?php ads($random_number,1); ?>
<div>your image or whatever</div>
<?php ads($random_number,2); ?>
```

---

```
<?php $random_number = rand(0,2); ?>

<?php ads($random_number,0); ?>
<div>your image or whatever</div>
<?php ads($random_number,1); ?>
<div>your image or whatever</div>
<?php ads($random_number,2); ?>
```

**COMPARISION FUNCTION**

// Now create a function to compare if random number generated is equal to ad's placeholder.

```
function ads($rand_num, $placeholder){
    if($rand_num == $placeholder){
        echo "<div> YOUR ADS CONTENT </div>";

    }
}
```

***Note : It's not meant to run perfectly , it's just a outline on how to achieve that specific goal.***

Comment: I am fetching products from the database using while loop and I want to display ads or anything  between these products in same order for more understand this you can see freekaamaal.com this is based on WordPress and in this they show random ads in place of products same as I do in  my core PHP hope you got it and btw way thanks lot for understanding :)

Comment: @anupdwivedi add you loop and code in there in your question and i will try to help you in that way

Comment: chk out dear added code in question @Nirpendra Patel

Comment: @anupdwivedi you havnt added main part in it :  loop

Comment: see from here this line display product in loop $counter = 1;
        while($ro = mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
        {       their i put Display Product in loop their only out put show and nothing else

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this (i tried to code it to be easy to understand):

```
<?php

function show_an_ad()
{
    $the_ad = '';

    switch (mt_rand(0,2))
    {
        case 0:
            $the_ad = 'ad0.jpg';
        break;
        case 1:
            $the_ad = 'ad1.jpg';
        break;
        case 2:
            $the_ad = 'ad2.jpg';
        break;
    }
    echo '<div class="col-md-3"><div class="hentry post1"><img src="'.$the_ad.'"></div></div>';
}


$ads_every_how_many_products = 3;


<div class="products-grids">
    <div class="col-md-12">
    <?php

        $id=$_GET['id'];

        $result1 = mysqli_query($con,"select * from products1 where sta='Active' order by id DESC LIMIT 0 , $resultsPerPage");

        $counter = 1;
        while($ro = mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
        {
            $nam1=substr($ro['pne'],0,60);
            $url1=$ro['url'];
            $description1=substr($ro['description'],0,200);
            $price1=$ro['price'];
            $price11=$ro['price1'];
            $bid1=$ro['company'];
            $image=$ro['image_name'];
            $time=$ro['time'];
            $tag=$ro['tag'];
    ?>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="hentry post1" id="post-225396">

             Display Product in loop

            </div>
        </div>
    <?php 
             if(!($counter%$ads_every_how_many_products))
             {
                 show_an_ad();
             }

             $counter++;
        }
        mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"> &nbsp;</div>
```

i don't have a php system here so there's a chance there could be a syntax error or something